# How to output from swift to a txt file, and open it

Tags: xcode, swift, file-io, read-write

I am trying to figure out how to write to a txt file and open it. Ive added a txt file to my project however nothing outputs to it when I try writing to it.

Ideally Id like to be able to click run, and then have my program execute, and then when I close it, be able to open the txt file through xCode, and notice a change of its contents.

I know in xCode, with C++, you can edit scheme and move the file to a folder you want, but I can't seem to find that feature with my iOS project in Swift.

Comment: You can't modify any file inside your bundle folder. All files located there are read only

Comment: If you would like to modify your file you will need to first copy it to a different folder that can be the documents folder, application support folder or the preferences folder